# Checking dropdown option is selected or not using elementToBeSelected / elementSelectionStateToBe.

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check whether option in the dropdown is selected or not. Webdriver should wait until value is selected and after that perform the next operation. I tried to use elementToBeSelected / elementSelectionStateToBe but i could not make it. How to use this?

Comment: Post the code you used and what happened when you used it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedCondition` "elementToBeSelected" should do what you want (it calls elementSelectionStateToBe with parameter true).
If it doesn't work for you, check that the passing argument is indeed the `WebElement` of option you want to have selected.

The code could look like as follows:

```
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("path/to/your/option[2]"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(option));
```

Another option for you is creating your own condition with anonymous class, that can be for example equality of values.

```
final Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("path/to/your/select"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                // this will get actual selected option and compare its value with expected value
                return select.getFirstSelectedOption().getAttribute("value").equals(expectedValue);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    WebElement searchDDwn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='edit-source']"));
    Select dropdown= new Select(searchDDwn);
    dropdown.selectByValue("Website");
    WebElement selected = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();

    boolean elementToBeSelected = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(selected));
    System.out.println("elementToBeSelected results"+elementToBeSelected);
```